# When sorting data how does excel handle duplicates?

Tags: excel, sorting

Say I have a table of 20K records and want to sort by colum A and C.  There are 20 records with identical A and C entries, how does excel decide how to order these 20 records?  Does it order by the value in the next available column not already defined in the sort?  Some magic sum of not null fields in that row? I am at a loss and can't find the answer anywhere, any clarification would really help as I don't think defining a sort by every available column is an efficient way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel SORT preserves the existing order of duplicate records.

Comment: Okay, is there a difference with Access then?  Performing the same sort in access and excel produce different results... should I post a new question or is this a valid way to ask a follow up?